# Как подключить правильно библеотеку materialize-css к webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, materialize-css

У меня возник вопрос, почему я не могу никак подключить `webpack` в эту библиотеку [materialize-css](https://github.com/Zevran/materialize-loader).
Есть идея использовать данный модуль `materialize-loader`. По-другому никак его не подключить? Или можно что-то попробовать? С `webpack` я ни разу не сталкивался и у меня практически нет опыта его использования. Я создал конфигурацию `вебпака` в файле, который `entry` я указал `import 'materialize-css'`
Ну и соответственно я этот модуль установил, но когда перезапускаю `webpack` и загружаю страницу, то никаких стилей я не вижу.
И у меня стоит вопрос, либо можно как-то их добавить и я неправильно делаю, или можно только с помощью модуля `materialize-loader` его подключить.

Comment: Вы используете `npm`?

Comment: @StackOverflow да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто надо с помощью `npm` установить библиотеку. А после установки оно сам поменяет конфигурацию `webpack`.

Для установки нужно запустить эту команду.

> npm install materialize-css

Или же можно с помощью `git` скачать библиотеку отсюда.

> git clone https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize.git

Ну а более подробную инструкцию можете прочитать [здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-css).

Но с начало кода вы создаете приложение вы должны установить `webpack` и `webpack-dev-server`.

> Подробности можете прочитать [здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server).

Comment: То есть я и так устаноил этот модуль, но webpack конфигурации че то не вижу изменение какие-то. Ладно, если возникнут вопросы, то спрошу

Comment: @Руслан Вы с начало так установите `webpack` и `webpack-dev-server`. После там уже будут конфиги, и когда новые модули уже установите, то конфиг меняется